# Determine which element's attributes' names match a list. Put result in a new attribute

Tags: xslt

I want to copy an element, but add to it a new attribute (@inTheList) whose value  identifies the attributes whose name was on a given list.

Input:

```
<element head="this" body="that" foot="the other">
```

and a list ["arm", "nose", "body", "head"] somehow represented.

Output:

```
<element head="this" body="that" foot="the other" inTheList="head body">
```

There's probably a clever XSLT-ish way to do this, but right now I can't even think of a brute-force way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:param name="names" as="xs:string*" select='"arm", "nose", "body", "head"'/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@*/name() = $names]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="inTheList" select="$names[. = current()/@*/name()]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5EN.

Comment: This is nice, but I wonder if it would be slow, if $names has dozens or hundreds of items. $names[. = current()/@*/name()] scans the whole list even when there are no more to check, right?

Comment: Well, it does in fact create a performance problem, increasing processing time to 2.5x.

Comment: You might want to raise a new question about the performance problem you see, stating exactly which XSLT processor you use, how you measured performance and which input data you have and which two solutions you measured and compared.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming input like this:

```
<root>
    <element head="this" nose="whatever" body="that" foot="the other"/>
    <element arm="this" body="that" foot="the other"/>
    <element foot="that"/>
</root>
```

Then this template will do what you want (explanation in comments):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Change this to match the elements you need to update -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <out>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="root/element"/>
        </out>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy an "element" and add a "theList" attribute listing selected attributes that are present -->
    <xsl:template match="element">
        <!-- This variable selects the target attributes -->
        <xsl:variable name="names">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@arm|@nose|@body|@head"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- copy all attributes -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <!-- add the new attribute if any of the target names are present -->
            <xsl:if test="$names != ''">
                <xsl:attribute name="theList">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($names)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- attribute name + a space separator -->
    <xsl:template match="element/@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' ')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<out>
    <element head="this"
             nose="whatever"
             body="that"
             foot="the other"
             theList="head nose body"/>
    <element arm="this" body="that" foot="the other" theList="arm body"/>
    <element foot="that"/>
</out>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could do simply (assuming XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="theList">
            <xsl:for-each select="@head | @body | @arm | @nose">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You will probably want to use this together with the *identity transform* template.